# How do I access/modify entities in a Database using Foreign Keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database, lazy-loading

I am attempting to access Entities from a Database for ensuring Data Integrity while performing changes in my Database.

I am testing different ways of altering the Foreign Key/Navigational Properties to point to different Rows in an associated Table.

My Child class looks like this,

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public decimal Balance { get; set; }    

public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
```

and the corrisponding Parent,

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts = new ICollection<Account>()
```

I am using the Unit of Work and Repository Patterns for accessing the Data, so in my testing class I do the following;

```
(uow = new UnitOfWork)

AccountType accountType1 = new AccountType() { Name = "Bank" };
AccountType accountType2 = new AccountType() { Name = "Loan" };

uow.AccountTypes.Add(accountType1);
uow.AccountTypes.Add(accountType2);
uow.Commit();

Account account1 = new Account() { Name = "RBS", Balance = 20, AccountTypeId = 1 };

uow.Accounts.Add(account1);
uow.Commit();
```

However on attempting then to access the `AccountType` property of `account1` this fails, I have tried setting the `AccountType` to a reference of `accountType1`, however when it comes to changing the `AccountType` from one to another, it requires that I load the new `accountType` from the database and then assign it to the `Account`, each time I make this change, rather than a simple change of the `Foreign key`. Is there not a way to change associations via the `Foreign Key` and still allow `lazy loading`? Or do I need to provide my own query, using the `Foreign Key` on the parent entity table?

Thanks!

**Edit**

If I create the entities and save them all in one context and then seek to access the Navigation properties this works, however if I dispose of the context and then in a new context perform the query, it fails to load the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign reference of parent to each child item like :

```
 (uow = new UnitOfWork)
    AccountType accountType1 = new AccountType() { Name = "Bank" };
    uow.AccountTypes.Add(accountType1);

Account account1 = new Account() { 
Name = "RBS", 
Balance = 20, 
AccountTypeId = 1 
AccountType = accountType1
};

uow.Accounts.Add(account1);
uow.Commit();
```

Also you don't need to commit at many places for one transaction

Comment: Thank you! That is the answer, however I have since found that because I am using EntityFramework Core I needed to install .Proxies in order to allow lazy loading. Which means I can simply set the AccountTypeId to a correct value and it sorts the connections out itself.